# How to plot a graph with time on y axis and date on x axis

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

How to draw a line graph with time on `y axis` and date on `x axis`... .  I have tried many plugins. but none of them are giving me option to put time on y axis. currently im trying to do it on http://www.chartphp.com/demo/#database/line.php   but i cant find a way to put time on `y axis`.   Both time and date are coming from my database.

Comment: have you tried fusion charts http://www.fusioncharts.com/ . its great for you and have many options

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend angularjs.
[chart application](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_chart_application.htm)